# Make excel filter and actualize automatically

Tags: excel, filter, automation, excel-2010, data-analysis

I have two sheets, one with a dashboard and another one with the data I need.

In **data** sheet: So many lines, that I filter by date. I need to know in Weeks, every record that contains in that, for example: I need to know how many records do I have in Week 43 (18-24 OCT). For that, I manually apply a filter and I count the number of records.

In **dashboard** sheet: I show the number of registers I got in the datasheet.

I want to automatize all this process, I want to do a formula in the dashboard sheet that can filter and show automatically the number of records I got in week X, excluding some variables I have in another column. The column I need contains letters and numbers, random (I need to sum these records, separated by date in weeks). All that I don't need to filter, what I need to exclude from my search starts with `AWBXXX` (random numbers too).

***Example here:***

[image: img]

What I need to filter, in green. What I don't need, red.

Please, help! :D

Comment: One easy way is using a helping column. First separate weeks from dates in a column (use `WEEKNUM()` function). Then use Countifs() formula.